# jwt をターミナルから decode したい

Tags: linux, unix, shell, jwt

web 開発をしていると、 jwt が得られたときに、その中身を確認したくなる場合があります。

例えば、もろもろの暗号系の鍵や証明書は、 `openssl` コマンドがあればその中身を確認したりなどできますが、それと同じようにこの jwt をデコードできると良いな、と考えました。

特に、コマンドラインからこれが実現できていると、 IDE などとの統合であったり、いろいろ取り回しが効くので、それで decode を行いたいと考えています。

## 質問

JWT (Json Web Token) があったとき、これをパースして中身を表示するが可能なコマンドラインツールには、どのようなものがありますか?